# Selecting columns by their data types in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I'd like to write a generic query that will be run on many different tables. It needs to select all columns from any table it runs on, but there is a catch: the select must exclude the columns with data type 'ntext'. Otherwise it's a simple

```
select * from <tableName>.
```

Any ideas?

I was able to create a query that lists all columns in a table that are not 'ntext'. Unfortunately I cannot pass this a parameter to another select, as it returns multiple results.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Tables aren't spreadsheets. Tables and column are similar to types and properties in a strongly typed language. The database engine needs to know the actual columns, whether they are covered by indexes, their types *and* the data statistics to produce a good execution plan. There's nothing "simple" about `select *` either, and DBAs hate such queries because they produce different results if the underlying columns change, breaking client applications, views, stored procedures

Comment: PS: `ntext` was abandoned somewhere between 2005 and 2008, replaced by `varchar(max)`. If you want to avoid loading unwanted data, `select *` is the wrong thing to do, whether you load BLOBs or not

Comment: You will need to dynamically build and execute your query.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, not sure at which part I was unclear. I'd like to write a select all statement, but I need to get rid of long texts, in this case ntext columns. The query will be run on multiple tables in the future, so I cannot write any specific query, therefore I need a generic solution.

Comment: @Stu could you please elaborate on this a little?

Comment: You will need to select from the system views, probably `information_schema.columns`, filtering on the `data_type` column and `table_name` to build the list of columns required.

Comment: You can query the `sys.column` table or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view to find a table's columns and their types. For `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` columns, the CHARACTER_MAX_LENGTH will be -1

Comment: @GergelyBohony you weren't unclear - the idea is bad. There's no single query, you'll have to write a new dynamic query for every table, every time, because tables change

Comment: Not to be too pedantic, but NTEXT was replaced with NVARCHAR. Using VARCHAR against an NTEXT value could result in data corruption/loss for any unmatched extended characters/glyphs.

Comment: Again, what are you trying to do? Who's going to consume that data? A client application can *easily* write a query that returns only the data it's going to display. If you use an ORM like EF Core, you can write a LINQ query that will only load the columns that will be displayed on a gird. There's no need for an `all except big columns` query, you can generate automatically a `just the ones I'll show` query

Comment: I would, in truth, also be surprised if you had many `ntext` columns. The use of the datatype means that the designer is stating that the value is likely to be more than 4,000 characters in length, and *up to* 1 billion characters. True, you may have a few of these in your database, but your post suggests you have many of them, which implies a misuse of the data type. (Not to again mention that `ntext` shouldn't be used any more anyway).

Comment: What does "get rid of long texts" mean? Do you just mean you want to generate a bunch of `SELECT` queries that list out all of the columns _except_ the ones that are `text`/`ntext`? What version of SQL Server are you using? What kind of app or person is going to consume the output of "give me all the data from _almost_ all the columns from all the tables"?

Comment: @Larnu I have roughly 600 tables, and the one I'm looking at has 15 ntext columns. And there are potentially dozens of DBs like this, to be processed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is for a Synapse copy activity, and all I have is a windows for a single SQL query.

Comment: @GergelyBohony create views then that return only what you want. That's *far* better than creating a new query every time and having to handle eg weird names and unexpected types. What you ask now will have to handle every weird case. You can create the view just once, perhaps even with a code generator, then optimize the individual views as needed

Comment: @GergelyBohony what do you think is more flexible, maintainable or just plain readable? The code in the answers here? Or generating a `CREATE VIEW` once using those queries, then adjusting the view whenever you want to make a tweak? What happens if you find a bug in the query generator code? Do you fix it in a single spot or do you have to fix it for every copy activity?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Man, I'm sorry, but why are you even commenting here? The amount of time you put into giving me options that I did not ask for (e.g. create views in an SQL server, where I only have read access, or don't use ntext, while I'm not the designer of the database or the application). No one asked you to rate my solution, or anyone's solution in the thread. If you cannot or don't want to help, that is fine, but why  adding 5 comments to explain why?

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a forum where you ask for something useful only to you. Both the question and answers have to be useful to *others*. What you ask is a bad idea and will harm others. Take that from a former SQL Server MVP. It sounds like a quick solution but in reality it's a huge pain - even if it worked, which it doesn't. Because you won't find any `ntext` fields, you'll find `varchar(max)`. Imagine finding a problem in your script once you have 10 tables already. There *are* good solutions, that take as much effort but are a lot easier to maintain and fix

Comment: To put it another way, it's your neck and your boss' Azure bill. What happens next month when you find out you uploaded several GB of text you though you excluded?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a shortest code to do so :

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(261) = 'dbo.sys_dm_db_missing_index_details'
               ,@SQL NVARCHAR(max) = N'';
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT ' + STRING_AGG('[' + CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS NVARCHAR(max)) + ']', ', ') + ' FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  DATA_TYPE <> 'ntext'
  AND   TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 2)
  AND   TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 1)
EXEC (@SQL);
```

You just have to replace the name of the table in the @TABLE_NAME variable to use it on a specific table.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`. Just tossing in a pair of square brackets isn't the same.

Comment: Unfortunately it ended up - if I understand well - over the max size for STRING_AGG
'Msg 9829, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.'

Comment: Just modified the data type of the string aggergation andd filtered on the target table

Comment: Impossible in TVF that doers not accept dynamic SQL. But you can create by a dynamic SQL a complete liste of views reflecting the table without any ntext columns

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the OPs requirement that they be able to run it for multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great idea, but I don't have a better way for you to achieve what you want.

Basically, you were on the right track with creating a query to hit up the system object views. You'd then turn this into a select statement, and pass it in to a cursor to be iterated over.

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR 
SELECT 'SELECT '''+sName+'.'+tName+''' AS TableName, ' +STRING_AGG('['+cName+']',', ') + ' FROM ['+sName+'].['+tName+']' AS tSQL
  FROM (
        SELECT c.name AS cName, t.name AS tName, s.name AS sName
          FROM sys.tables t
            INNER JOIN sys.columns c
              ON t.object_id = c.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.systypes st
              ON c.system_type_id = st.xtype
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
              ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
         WHERE st.name NOT IN ('TEXT', 'NTEXT','IMAGE','BINARY')
           AND (st.name NOT IN ('NVARCHAR','VARCHAR') OR c.max_length < 50)
       ) a
 GROUP BY tName, sName
DECLARE @tSql NVARCHAR(MAX)
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @tSql
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
 PRINT @tSQL
 EXEC sp_executeSQL @tSQL
 FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @tSql
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Cursors are bad, you shouldn't use them, except when you don't have much of a choice.
Warning: If you have a lot of tables, with a lot of data, this is going to run for a long time. You shouldn't use this in production until you have fully tested it and determined for yourself that it's not going to cause your system a problem, and you accept that you're doing so at your own risk.

Comment: @PatrickHurst thanks a lot, will look into this soon, honestly I'm that familiar with the whole cursor concept.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`. Just tossing in a pair of square brackets isn't the same.

Comment: @CodeNovice Who cares about cursor performance and they are slightly faster in some other database platform? We are talking about a cursor being used to generate T-SQL commands. If that's the crux of any performance issue there is a serious problem.

Comment: Well - people like me would care.  When I first came over to SQL Server I was trying to use Cursors the same as I did when working in Oracle for 8 years... alas... I learned to not use cursors in SQL Server.  And why do you care that I care?  Who cares.

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off of @SQLpro's answer.  I wanted it to be more flexible.  This version will allow you to enter the Table Parameter with or without the schema prefix.  It will also allow you to enter no parameter and if no table parameter the query will pull ALL Tables.  If the table parameter is typed in without the schema the query will filter on All Schemas where the TableName = @TABLE_NAME.

Another caveat is when using PRINT it does have a max output.  This can be accounted for and while you are able to do some magic to allow PRINT to spit out an endless amount of data I instead prefer to set my Query Results Output from the default GRID to TEXT should I need or want to copy out each generated SELECT statement for each table.

> Example below using PRINT.  PRINT has a character limit and so see 2nd example of how to easily get around this.

```
/* DynamicSelect.sql 
 | Desc: This version uses PRINT to spit out the SELECT statements.
*/

DECLARE @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(261) = 'dbo.CT_DogBreed' --'dbo.CT_DogBreed' 'import.CT_DogBreed'
      , @SQL        NVARCHAR(max) = N''
;

SELECT @SQL = CONCAT(@SQL, N'SELECT ', STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME), ', ' ), ' FROM ', c.TABLE_SCHEMA ,'.', c.TABLE_NAME, char(13))
    --CONCAT(N'SELECT ', STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME), ', ' ), ' FROM ', c.TABLE_SCHEMA ,'.', c.TABLE_NAME) AS DynamicSQL
    --, c.TABLE_SCHEMA
    --, c.TABLE_NAME
    --, PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 2) AS SchemaPartFilterOnParameter
    --, PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 1) AS TablePartFilterOnParameter

FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE  DATA_TYPE <> 'ntext'

    AND  1 = CASE WHEN PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 2) IS NOT NULL /* If TRUE then filter on Schema */
             THEN 
                CASE WHEN c.TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             /* Else if False perform no filter on Schema and return 1 for TRUE and not apply Schema Filter - Returns All Schemas */
             ELSE 1 END

    AND  1 = CASE WHEN PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 1) IS NOT NULL /* If TRUE then filter on Table */
             THEN 
                CASE WHEN c.TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             /* Else if False perform no filter on Table and return 1 for TRUE and not apply Table Filter - Returns All Tables  */
             ELSE 1 END

GROUP BY c.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME

PRINT @SQL

--EXEC (@SQL);
```

> Not using PRINT - Set Query Results to Text.  PRINT has a character limit.

```
/* DynamicSelect.sql 
 | Desc: Using this version you can output the data to the Grid or
 |       set your Query Ouput from the default GRID output to TEXT.
 |       Comment out all fields except the DynamicSQL Column if you output as TEXT.
*/

DECLARE @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(261) = 'dbo.CT_DogBreed' --'dbo.CT_DogBreed' 'import.CT_DogBreed'
      , @SQL        NVARCHAR(max) = N''
;

SELECT --@SQL = CONCAT(@SQL, N'SELECT ', STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME), ', ' ), ' FROM ', c.TABLE_SCHEMA ,'.', c.TABLE_NAME, char(13))
    CONCAT(N'SELECT ', STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME), ', ' ), ' FROM ', c.TABLE_SCHEMA ,'.', c.TABLE_NAME) AS DynamicSQL
    , c.TABLE_SCHEMA
    , c.TABLE_NAME
    , PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 2) AS SchemaPartFilterOnParameter
    , PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 1) AS TablePartFilterOnParameter

FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE  DATA_TYPE <> 'ntext'

    AND  1 = CASE WHEN PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 2) IS NOT NULL /* If TRUE then filter on Schema */
             THEN 
                CASE WHEN c.TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             /* Else if False perform no filter on Schema and return 1 for TRUE and not apply Schema Filter - Returns All Schemas */
             ELSE 1 END

    AND  1 = CASE WHEN PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 1) IS NOT NULL /* If TRUE then filter on Table */
             THEN 
                CASE WHEN c.TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             /* Else if False perform no filter on Table and return 1 for TRUE and not apply Table Filter - Returns All Tables  */
             ELSE 1 END

GROUP BY c.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME

--PRINT @SQL

--EXEC (@SQL);
```

> Screenshot of how to set the Query Results from the Default Grid to Text.  Navigate to Query --> Results to --> Results to Text.

[image: Set Query Results to Text]

> Gif showing both PRINT and Query Results to Text.

[image: Gif Demo using PRINT and Query Results to Text]